# Why the number is not negative when we have 1 in MSB in subtraction of hexadecimal numbers

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, subtraction, twos-complement

I'm learning about addition/subtraction in Assembly. I searched for articles to see how to know if a hexadecimal number is negative/positive and saw this page below, from [this site](http://www.ee.nmt.edu/%7Erison/ee308_spr02/supp/020123.pdf)

[Subtraction part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Mke.png)

My question is for the left-most example in the screenshot. We have 1 as MSB but N bit is still 0, do I miss something?
There is also a similar example in the addition part of the same pdf which have answer 1E and N bit is 1.

[Addition part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kS7K.png)

Answer (score 3):

The MSB is not the highest bit that is ON in the binary representation of the number, but rather corresponds to the highest bit in the container that holds your number.

Consider these examples:

The number 1Eh is 11110b in binary.
If we consider a **byte-sized** container then its contents is 00011110b. The highest bit is not set, therefore the number is positive.
If we consider a **word-sized** container then its contents is 0000000000011110b. The highest bit is not set, therefore the number is positive.

The number 85h is 10000101b in binary.
If we consider a **byte-sized** container then its contents is 10000101b. The highest bit is set, therefore the number is negative.
If we consider a **word-sized** container then its contents is 0000000010000101b. The highest bit is not set, therefore the number is positive.